# How to check if a url on same host or not

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I am trying to pars an html page (using [Html Agility pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)) and extract all image links. Now I want to see if the link is on the same host or not. Is the following code covers all the scenarios? is there any better solution to achieve this?

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img/@src"))
{
    var link = node.Attributes["src"].Value.Trim();

    if (link.StartsWith("http", true, null) || link.StartsWith("//"))
        //the link is not on the same host
}
```

Comment: Seems reasonable, excepting `httpfiles/funny_cats.gif` and perhaps Value.Trim().ToLower();

Comment: What about `ftp://` ?

Comment: There might be a "base" tag under "head" which will could cause all the relative links in a page to actually be retrieved from another site. I think you should check the existence of that tag too. [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following regular expression:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(link, @"^(\w+:)*\/\/"))
{
   // The link is not on the same host
}
```

This will work for any protocol, and won't match local directories or files starting with `http` such as @AlexK example in the comments